# Just say No on Just Say No

Tags: monopoly-deal

Is it possible to play a just say no on a just say no? Will the second just say no cancel out the previous just say no?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this, and if the person playing the first "No" is also holding the third "No", they can play it against the second "No" to result in a chain with the net effect of just the original "No" negating the targeted action card for that player.

Comment: Logocally...it does make sense. But then this falls apart at the time when the Just say no is happening between multiple people. For e.g.


Player 1: Asked for rent

Player 2: played JSN
Player 3: played JSN
Player 1: played JSN

Lets say, this negates the JSN for Player 3, but Player 1 will then lose rent from Player 2. Then the Player 1's JSN didnt do its job properly!!

Comment: The way you've written that chain makes it impossible to tell whose No is acting on what, and whether your statement is correct. But either the first No is not negated because the third cancels the second, or both second and third are used on the same first, so one is wasted and makes no sense, or the third acts on the rent leaving the same result as the first would have. In all cases the No has done its job...

Comment: Why can player 3 play a JSN if it's not his turn and rent isn't being collected from him?

Comment: Because rent on a two-colour Rent card is collected from everybody. Where do you get the idea that the third plater isn't being hit for rent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Just Say No on a Just Say No.

The "Cards in more detail" section of the rulebook say:

> **Just Say No:**
>
> Use this card at any time to cancel the effect when another player plays any action card against you.  If that player has another Just Say No card, they can use it to cancel yours... sorry!

Answer (score -2):

If player 1, on his (1st/2nd but not 3rd) turn plays a deal breaker on player 2 to take a set, player 2 plays a JSN to this, player 1 can play a JSN to the JSN and still take the set.

Comment: This does not add anything that was not in the existing answser.